# How to do filter on multiple key value pairs in an Struct Column of BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a BQ table containing a `labels` column which is of type `Record`. `labels` will have values like {'a':'x', 'b':'y'}.
I want to filter the records containing {'a':'x', 'b':'y'}.

I initially tried with basic SQL query:

```
with data_sept as(
  select *  from `k.l.m`
  where invoice.month = '202309'
)
select * from data_sept , UNNEST(labels) as label
where 
-- (label.key = 'a' and label.value = 'x') and (label.key = 'b' and label.value = 'y');
```

This returned no result. So I googled a bit and tried this query:

```
with data_sept as(
  select *  from `k.l.m`
  where invoice.month = '202309'
)
select * from data_sept , UNNEST(labels) as label
where 
(label.key, label.value)  = ('a', 'x') and (label.key, label.value) = ('b', 'y');
```

even this returns no results. I can confirm that there are records containing {a:x} pair in the table.
But if I try:

```
with data_sept as(
  select *  from `k.l.m`
  where invoice.month = '202309'
)
select * from data_sept , UNNEST(labels) as label
where (label.key, label.value) = ('b', 'y');
```

This returns records.

I want to have multiple key value pairs filter and then group the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the `UNNEST` is doing a cross join between each row and every element of its labels array. The output will be 1 row for each label, duplicating the original row if there are multiple labels. If you filter on the unnested column `label` it can only take a single value (it can't be a and b at the same time).

You can filter on the labels using a `SELECT` over the array in the `WHERE` clause, without unnesting.

```
WITH data_sept AS (
  SELECT
    '202309' AS invoice_month,
    123 AS order_id,
    32 AS amount,
    [
      STRUCT('a' AS lkey, 'x' AS lvalue),
      STRUCT('b' AS lkey, 'y' AS lvalue)
    ]
    AS labels
)

SELECT
  invoice_month,
  SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM data_sept
WHERE
  (SELECT lvalue FROM data_sept.labels WHERE lkey = 'a') = 'x'
  AND (SELECT lvalue FROM data_sept.labels WHERE lkey = 'b') = 'y'
GROUP BY 1
```